# How to get a property by this name in String?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to access to a property by the name si string format.

If I have a class like that:

```
class PrefsState {
  String a;

  PrefsState({
    this.a,

  })
```

How can I do something like that:

```
PrefsState test= PrefsState(a: "it is a test");
String key = "a";

print(test[key]);
```

Of course is not working. There is a way to do that in Dart ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use reflection/mirrors in flutter.
What you can do, which is tedious, is use maps.

```
class PrefsState { 
   String a; 
   const PrefsState({ this.a, });
   dynamic getProp(String key) => <String, dynamic>{
    'a' : a,
    }[key];
}
```

It's probably better to build the map in the constructor, but if you want const constructors then you'll have to settle for this. Likely won't make much of a difference unless you have a million parameters anyway. Then you use it like so:

```
PrefsState test= PrefsState(a: "it is a test");
String key = "a"; 
print(test.getProp(key));
```

I don't think there is a less cumbersome way of doing this, but would love to be proven wrong :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with mirrors, but mirrors don't work in dart2js or flutter.  You can use code builders to get at this, but the real question is what is your need for this?

Comment: Maybe my add is not well done design. I have multiple textfield and I use flutter_bloc to change settings. I have a state with 10 parameters, and now for each parameter I create an event and I repeat the code.  I want to change to have a generic event to set any parameter and store it in the state  by using mirrors. Maybe it is not the good solution. My description is enough clear ?

Comment: Perhaps you want a Map, rather than a class with members.