# Flutter: Convert String to class field name during runtime

Tags: flutter, dart, reflection

Is it possible to "convert" a String which is **dynamically** generated in my code, into a class field/variable name?

The issue I am facing is that I have a *database* which returns a unique name (as `String`) for each of its rows. I want to use this name in order to find the corresponding field (with the same spelling as the database entry) of a **generated** class that holds all my translations within its various fields. As this class is generated and subject to constant change there is no way to convert into a `Map` and thereby access its fields as `values` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55445624/how-to-get-a-property-by-this-name-in-string).

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  // Suppose this is a dynamic list returned from a database query
  final List<String> listFromDB = ['one', 'three', 'two'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: listFromDB.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
              _listItemBuilder(context, index, listFromDB)),
    );
  }
}

Widget _listItemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index, List<String> listFromDB) {
  // suppose this is some map with translations of different languages. 
  final labels = Labels.translations['languageCode'];

  final String dbUniqueName = listFromDB[index];
  // QUESTION: How can I use the above String dbUniqueName to access a field of the
  // AnyClass class in order to return the corresponding value, e.g. "eins" for 
  // its name "one"?
  
  print(labels.dbUniqueName) // ERROR: Not compiling because dbUniqueName is a String


  return null;
}

// GENERATED: The below code can not be changed as it is generated

class Labels {
  static final Map<String, AnyClass> translations = {
    'languageCode' : AnyClass(one: 'eins', two: 'zwei', three: 'drei')
  };
}

class AnyClass {
  AnyClass({this.one, this.two, this.three});

  final String one;
  final String two;
  final String three;
}
```

I have read this old [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17766) on GitHub on the same issue. But it seems there was no solution at that time. I also came across [reflections in Dart](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.3/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html) but I am not sure whether they provide a solution in the above described case.

Thanks for any help and advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually use methods like the one below in Dart language to reference a class variable using a `String`.

```
Widget _listItemBuilder(
    BuildContext context, int index, List<String> listFromDB) {
  final labels = Labels.translations['languageCode'];

  final String dbUniqueName = listFromDB[index];

  print(getByFieldName(dbUniqueName, labels));

  return null;
}

String getByFieldName(String name, AnyClass anyClass) {
  switch (name) {
    case 'one':
      return anyClass.one;
    case 'one':
      return anyClass.one;
    case 'one':
      return anyClass.one;
    default:
      throw ('Unsupported');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reflection is provided in the mirrors package, but that package requires the VM and is therefore not supported in Flutter. Have you looked at the [reflectable](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable) package?

If that doesn't work, a simple `Map` could do the trick of translating a String in to an object's field, e.g.:

```
var object = AnyClass();
var field = {'one': object.one, 'two' object.two, 'three': object.three};
print(field['two']); // will print object.two;
```

Comment: Thank you! Using a `Map` is a good idea, but in my case anything related to `AnyClass` is generated by a third-party extension, so I cannot transfer it into a `Map` as you suggested... any ideas?