# Is it possible to use a variable within a variable name?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class for Player that has nextDate, loginDate and saveDate.
Below code works fine and able to retrieve the fields.

```
      DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
          await db.collection(Paths.playersPath).doc(uid).get();
      Player player = Player.fromFirestore(documentSnapshot);
      print('print ${player.nextDate}');
      print('print ${player.loginDate}');
      print('print ${player.saveDate}');
```

My question now is if it is possible to use a variable for the nextDate, loginDate and saveDate so that I can just pass which date should I retrieve.
I tried the following but it is not working.

```
String dateName = 'nextDate';
DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
          await db.collection(Paths.playersPath).doc(uid).get();
      Player player = Player.fromFirestore(documentSnapshot);
      print('print ${player.$dateName}');
```

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the code snippet is concerned, I can see you have already defined a method `fromFirebase` to serialize it, in that case you must extract the data payload from the `DocumentSnapshot` provided by the Firebase DB by using the `data` method provided by the `DocumentSnapshot` class. The problem in your case is you're trying to serialize the `DocumentSnapshot` itself which is not a class of type `Map<String, dynamic>` which is need for json serialization. If you take a look at the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html), the `data` method provides a `Map<String, dynamic>`

Another alternative could be

If you are using `FlutterFire` plugins that are officially developed by the Firebase and Flutter teams, you can use the `withConverter` method which can serialize the response for you to the `Player` class in your case. [Here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#typing-collectionreference-and-documentreference) you can find more info about the same.

Answer (score 1):

unluckily, in Flutter `mirrors` are not available.
You can look it up in the [official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#does-flutter-come-with-a-reflection--mirrors-system) about this matter.

Nonetheless, the most straightforward workaround is using a `Map`, so that the keys in that map are your options, and the values the actual property you want to use.

There's a good example in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55445624/how-to-get-a-property-by-this-name-in-string).