# How to retrieve the value of an object by using it's key name as a String?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a typical class userData.

```
class userData ({K1:V1,K2:V2,K3:V3})
```

But i want to retrieve the data from several of them at the same time.

```
userData1 {K1:V1,K2:V2,K3:V3}
userData2 {K1:V4,K2:V5,K3:V6}
userData3 {K1:V7,K2:V7,K3:V8}
```

instead of using typical direct way:

```
print ("${userData1.K1} ${userData2.K1} ${userData3.K1}") ;
```

I want to access the data in an indirect method by using the key name as a String. Something like this:

```
String MyKey = 'K1';
print ("${userData1[MyKey]} ${userData2[MyKey]} ${userData3[MyKey]}") ;
```

Is there a way to retireve the values by using the key name as a String?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Seems like this may be a case of the [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - Why do you want to do this? If we know a bit more about the underlying problem you're trying to solve, we may be able to help you find a better solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a property by this name in String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55445624/how-to-get-a-property-by-this-name-in-string)
There is already an answer to this question, I will even formulate an answer, but it was the same as the already existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution that worked for me by creating a new dynamic in my class:

```
class MyClass{

    ....

  dynamic getProp(String key) => <String, dynamic>{
    'K1': K1,
    'K2': K2,
    'K3': K3,
  }[key].toString();
  }
}
```

With this i can retrieve with this line:

```
print(MyClass.getProp("K1"));
```

And so to get the data from my array, it work like this:

```
userData1 {K1:V1,K2:V2,K3:V3}
userData2 {K1:V4,K2:V5,K3:V6}
userData3 {K1:V7,K2:V7,K3:V8}

myKey = "K1";
print ("${userData1.getProp("K1")} ${userData2.getProp("K1")} ${userData3.getProp("K1")}"); // prints "V1 V4 V7"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.

You may be looking for `__getitem__`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.getitem

Consider

```
d = dict(a=1, b=2)
```

When you ask for `d['a']`, you are calling `d.__getitem__('a')` behind the scenes.

There is an opportunity for your container class to inherit from `dict`,
and override `__getitem__`, if you wish to add behavior like logging,
or something fancier.

---

This is similar to the `str()` protocol that you likely are already familiar with.
Overriding `__str__` will change the behavior of `str(...)`
and things that call it, such as `format(...)`.

You should certainly review the [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) documentation.

---

When you write some code that addresses the need to your liking,
*do* post it here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer